# Computing conditional density of continuous rv

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ two r.v with joint density function

$$ f_{XY}(x,y) = \begin{cases} 5x^2y, \; \; \; -1\leq x \leq 1,, \; \; \; 0 < y \leq |x| \\ 0 \; \; \; \; ow \end{cases}$$

I need to find $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$. Clearly,

$$ f_Y(y) = \int_{-1}^1 f_{XY}(x,y)dx = \frac{10}{3} y $$

Now, it follows that

$$ f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{ f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} = \frac{3x^2}{2}$$

Is this a correct way to find conditional density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is correct but you are making mistakes.

For a fixed $y\in(0,1)$:

$\begin{aligned}\int_{-1}^{1}f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)dx & =\int_{-1}^{-y}5x^{2}ydx+\int_{y}^{1}5x^{2}ydx\\
 & =5y\left[\left[\frac{1}{3}x^{3}\right]_{-1}^{-y}+\left[\frac{1}{3}x^{3}\right]_{y}^{1}\right]\\
 & =5y\left[\left[-\frac{1}{3}y^{3}-\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)\right]+\left[\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3}y^{3}\right]\right]\\
 & =5y\left[\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{3}y^{3}\right]\\
 & =\frac{10}{3}y\left[1-y^{3}\right]
\end{aligned}
$

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ takes value $0$ outside $[-1,-y]\cup[y,1]$.